# Overflow Error Solidity

Tags: solidity, error, overflow

Made a mint function from a finished traded contract and now it throws an overflow error on pancake
I think we minted too much token

Comment: Can you share the source code and a failed transaction hash?

Comment: https://dashboard.tenderly.co/tx/bsc/0xafcc7e598a56baa3d7908620edd174c68f55b8d4913fd6a52303dfc10bdeccda

 We made too many mint function and now it throws an error like this

contratc: 0x58472700522605db6505ed6aea866f57d9873c44

Comment: Hey bro? Will you help me……???

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not quite familiar with pancake contracts so I don't know for sure. It seems the token pair has too much SweetDOGE. Something that might work is to burn LP tokens, so some of the SweetDOGE will be moved to another account, but I'm not sure if that will work. I'd suggest to run some unit tests before deploying another contract.